# Anyone knows some small library for downloading web pages?

Tags: c++, download

I need something that will allow my C++ program to download a HTML source of some page. Can someone recommend me a library to do that? I'd prefer as simple thing as it can be. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows use [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 5):

Try cURLpp from http://curlpp.org. See also its [example code](http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples).

Comment: I have some trouble with compiling this with codeblocks and mingw. By importing VC project into cb i get error: "cannot find include file "curl/curl.h"; no such file or directory". mingw32-make also doesn't work (it complains about missing separator on line 15 of makefile or something).